# TOC Running Head

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, books

I have found any number of answers to how you might change running heads of chapters and how you can change the appearance of chapter titles in the table of contents, but I can't find how you can change the running head of the table of contents itself in the book class.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try along the following lines. Note that the ToC running heads are usually the same as chapter running heads.

```
% tocheadprob.tex  SE 567005
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings} %% the default for book

\pagestyle{plain} %% use this style for the ToC
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{headings} %% back to the default style for chapters
\chapter{One}
\section{First}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage} %% just to have a 2 page ToC
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

Use whatever pagestyles you like.